# add a string to a file without line break

Tags: string, shell, unix

I searched and found "echo -n" and "printf" are solution for this, but they are working a bit quirky on my machines.

here:

```
[wadhwaso@nxnixd01 ~]$ echo "hello" >> test
[wadhwaso@nxnixd01 ~]$ cat test
hello
[wadhwaso@nxnixd01 ~]$ echo -n "world" >> test
[wadhwaso@nxnixd01 ~]$ cat test
hello
world
[wadhwaso@nxnixd01 ~]$ echo -n " seriously?" >> test
[wadhwaso@nxnixd01 ~]$ cat test
hello
world seriously?
```

same is the case with "printf". It works 2nd 3rd 4th time and so on but not the first time.

I am not very comfortable with awk and sed, thats why I wanted to use these.

If I dont have any choice can someone tell me how to add "elevator=noop" in /etc/grub.conf via awk or sed ??

Answer:
`sed -i '$s/$/,string/' file` ..

Comment: Thanks for the edit John. I was there editing but you were fast.

Comment: Asking two *different* questions inside one is not a very good idea.

Comment: :) .. I lerned something, check John's answer's first 2 lines. 

P.s. It was not two questions, That was just an attempt to tell all the "greycat's" there that I did a research before posting and to describe my problem. sometimes describing helps.

Comment: By the way, you should accept John's answer, it seems to be pretty concise for both questions :)

Comment: True that .. His answer was very informative ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-n` option controls whether a newline is added at the *end* of the echo. That very first `echo "hello"` writes `hello\n` to the file; that's where the newline is coming from.

To add a kernel option try one of these. Each of them searches for the `kernel` line in grub.conf and appends " elevator=noop" to the end.

```
sed '/kernel/ s/$/ elevator=noop/' /etc/grub.conf

awk '$1 == "kernel" { $0 = $0 " elevator=noop" } { print } ' /etc/grub.conf
```

Comment: I guess I'll have to use sed or awk

Comment: is there any thing from which we can check if the line has \n at the end or not ?

Comment: @Stunn3r All lines except maybe the last one have a `\n` at the end. That's what separates one line from the next! And it is good practice in UNIX for the last line to have a `\n` at the end, too. If you open a text file in vi it will show `[noeol]` if the last line doesn't have one.

Comment: Can you please explain why we used the word "kernel" there in commands ?

Comment: Also those sed and awk commands simply cat'ed the files. nothing else.

by cat'ed I mean "cat /etc/grub.conf"

Comment: @Stunn3r Use `sed -i` to overwrite the source file. With awk it's more complicated, you need to save the output to a temp file then overwrite the original file with the temp file, like `awk '...' orig > temp; mv temp orig`.

Comment: Hey John, Thanks, the "-i" worked :) .. 
Here:
`"sed -i '$s/$/,string/' file"` .. I still dont know why you introduced the word "kernel" there in your commands ?

Answer (score 0):

Oftentimes your shell will have a built-in echo. This can cause a fair amount of confusion. You should try an absolute path to an echo if you're seeing odd behavior, it may fix the problem.

```
[user@host ]$ which echo
/usr/bin/echo
[user@host ]$ echo --version
--version
[user@host]$ /usr/bin/echo --version
echo (GNU coreutils) 8.15
...
```

As it turns out my echo, 8.15 and bash 4.2.37 on x64 linux appear to "do the right thing":

```
[user@host ]$ echo -n "Hi" > /tmp/hi
[user@host ]$ cat /tmp/hi
Hi[user@host ]$
```

Comment: The file already have a /n at the end . so for first "echo -n", it wont work

Answer (score 0):

Use printf rather than echo.
echo is non portable and awkward to use

Comment: The file already have a /n at the end . so printf or echo wont work for the first time but work after first. Check John's answer, that is very clear